# System.Import in Typescript not overriding the default path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am a newbie to Typescript and Angular2.I have an `app` folder where I am creating ts files and I am trying to generate transpiled 'js' files to another folder built. 'Js' files are being generated successfully but when I try to `import` the files to html using `System.import('built')`, scripts are not being refernced and throwing `404`. Both 'app' and 'built' folders are added to the root.
Here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "built"
  }
}
```

And here I am importing the scripts to index.html :

```
System.import('built').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

Any help.

Edit : Here I have added the systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: I just tested it with quickstart-app and in my case its working if I do `System.import('built').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });` Can you show me your `systemjs.config.js`?

Comment: @micronyks updated the question with systmjs.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change mapping of **app** to **built** as shown,

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'built',            //<-----changed 'app' to 'built'...
      ...
      ...
}
```

Comment: Happens  ! Enjoy Angular2.